# Standardize and reduce repeating same procedures in my coding Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I am aware that my VBA code can be improved.I am pretty sure that my code can look better.I would like to standardize and reduce repeating same procedures. Does this will improve efficiency too? Can I have some guide lines for this? Where to start? I would be glad to have some examples from you! I would like to learn to write code more efficiently.

```
' Kanban_Color
'


Dim white, red, green, orange, peach, yellow, pink, blue, maroon, violet, black As Long

white = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White
red = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
 green = RGB(215, 228, 188) 'Green
 orange = RGB(228, 109, 10) 'Orange
 peach = RGB(242, 174, 92) 'Peach
 yellow = RGB(255, 255, 113) 'Yellow
 pink = RGB(255, 182, 193) 'Pink
 blue = RGB(147, 205, 221) 'Blue
 maroon = RGB(149, 55, 53) 'Maroon
 violet = RGB(204, 192, 218) 'Violet
 black = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black

 ws_kanban.Select
 Set shelf_card = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E10")
 Set trav_card = ActiveSheet.Range("A12:G21")
 Set int_supp = ActiveSheet.Range("C17:E17")
 Set int_supp_loc = ActiveSheet.Range("C20:E20")
 Set section = ws_kanban_data.Range("G2")
 Set section2 = ActiveSheet.Range("G2:H2")
 Set warning = ActiveSheet.Range("G6")
 Set warning2 = ActiveSheet.Range("G7")
 Set issue_type = ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F10")
 Set issue_type_trav = ActiveSheet.Range("H12:H21")
 Set types = ws_kanban_data.Range("F2")
 section2.Select

If section = "MECH" Then
    shelf_card.Interior.Color = green
    trav_card.Interior.Color = green
ElseIf section = "LAB" Then
    shelf_card.Interior.Color = orange
    trav_card.Interior.Color = orange
ElseIf section = "HOCC" Then
    shelf_card.Interior.Color = peach
    trav_card.Interior.Color = peach
ElseIf section = "SASW" Then
    shelf_card.Interior.Color = yellow
    trav_card.Interior.Color = yellow
ElseIf section = "SAMO" Then
    shelf_card.Interior.Color = pink
    trav_card.Interior.Color = pink
ElseIf section = "RRC" Then
    shelf_card.Interior.Color = blue
    trav_card.Interior.Color = blue
ElseIf section = "CUST" Then
    shelf_card.Interior.Color = maroon
    trav_card.Interior.Color = maroon
ElseIf section = "PE" Then
    shelf_card.Interior.Color = red
    trav_card.Interior.Color = red
ElseIf section = "PACK" Then
    shelf_card.Interior.Color = violet
    trav_card.Interior.Color = violet
ElseIf section = "LC" Then
    shelf_card.Interior.Color = white
    trav_card.Interior.Color = white
Else
    section2.Font.Color = white
    warning.Value = "Check Section!!"
        For i = 1 To 2
            shelf_card.Interior.Color = red
            trav_card.Interior.Color = red
            warning.Interior.Color = red
            warning.Font.Color = white
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            shelf_card.Interior.Color = white
            trav_card.Interior.Color = white
            warning.Interior.Color = white
            warning.Font.Color = red
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Next i
    warning.Font.Color = white
    warning.Interior.Color = red
End If

If types = "M" Then
    issue_type.Value = "Manual Issue "
    issue_type_trav.Value = "Manual Issue "
    issue_type.Interior.Color = black
    issue_type_trav.Interior.Color = black
    issue_type.Font.Color = white
    issue_type_trav.Font.Color = white
ElseIf types = "B" Then
    issue_type.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    issue_type_trav.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    issue_type.Font.Color = white
    issue_type_trav.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Else
    issue_type.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    issue_type_trav.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    issue_type.Font.Color = white
    issue_type_trav.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    warning2.Value = "Check Type!!"
        For i = 1 To 2
            shelf_card.Interior.Color = red
            trav_card.Interior.Color = red
            warning2.Interior.Color = red
            warning2.Font.Color = white
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            shelf_card.Interior.Color = white
            trav_card.Interior.Color = white
            warning2.Interior.Color = white
            warning2.Font.Color = red
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Next i
    warning2.Font.Color = white
    warning2.Interior.Color = red
End If
```

Comment: At this site you find programming help, not tuition. There is a site related to this one where they do code review. You might try that. With that said, note that of the variables you declare, only the last one is of Long type. All others, undefined, are Variants by default. Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code. Consider using `Select Case` instead of `ElseIf`. Consider determining the value to be set to *Issue_type* (for example) using Select, writing it to a variable. Then assign that variable to `issue_type.Value`

Comment: Adding to @Variatus's comment:  The "related site" is [codereview.se].  (Also, consider replacing your Colour section at the top with an [`Enum` Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/enum-statement) at the top of the module, since [`RGB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function) returns a `Long`)